# Proving the sequence $f_{x_n}(x)= (n+1)x^n$ converges in distribution

Tags: probability

I am preparing for a final exam and just working on sample problems.

> Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be an infinite sequence of continuous random variables such that $f_{x_n}(x)= (n+1)x^n$ for $0<x<1$ and $0$ otherwise.
>
> Show that $\{X_n\}$ converges in distribution to the degenerate r.v $X$ where $P(X=1)=1$.

*Progress*: I have found the cumulative distribution for both $F_x$ and $F_{x_n}$:

- $F_{x_n} = x^n$ for $0<x<1$, $1$ for $x\ge 1$, and $0$ for $x<0$
- $F_x(x)= 1$ for $x\ge 0 $ and $0$ when $x<0$.

I don't know how to prove it from there on.

Comment: What have you done so far to try and solve this problem?

Comment: i have found the cumulative distribution for both Fx and Fxn  for

Comment: Fxn = x^n for 0<x<1 , 1 for x>=1, and 0 for x<=0

Comment: Fx(x)= 1 for x>=0 and 0 when x<0.

Comment: i don't know how to prove it from there on

Comment: how can i prove that for | x^(n+1)-1|< epsilon

Comment: I edited the question. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: You are already very close to the answer. Just remember that $X_n\stackrel{d}{\to}X$ if $F_{X_n}(x)\to F(x)$ at all the points $x$ where $F_{X_n} $ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A sequence of rvs converge in distribution is the sequence of corresponding characteristic functions converge for points where the function sequence is continuous. This is [Levy's continuity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem).

So find the characteristic function sequence and show its convergence.